# Play 2.5 error - CompletionStage<WSResponse> cannot be converted to F.Promise<WSResponse>

Tags: java, web-services, playframework-2.5

Hoping someone can help. I'm trying to upgrade from Play 2.4 to 2.5. After upgrading, I'm getting errors in the JavaController class. One of the errors show

> [error] /Play-2-JS-2.5/app/controllers/JavaController.java:87: 
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage cannot
>   be converted to play.libs.F.Promise
>   [error] WS.url("http://example.com").get()

It looks as though perhaps WSReponse might have been deprecated when going to 2.5. I tried to replace F.Promise with CompletionStage here on line 87 https://github.com/btgrant-76/Play-2-Java-Scala-Java-8-Async-Comparison/blob/6a85cf31cfb804ef20bacf8e14d30ce46cc9307c/app/controllers/JavaController.java#L87 but get the same error. I've been googling for quite sometime and found topics around Dependency Injection however, there aren't any examples. Any examples and/or where to go to from here would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replaced

```
final F.Promise<WSResponse> responsePromise = WS.url("http://example.com").get();
```

with

```
final CompletionStage<WSResponse> responsePromise = WS.url("http://example.com").get();
```

and still get the same error, then things to check include:

1. Are you saving the source code before you recompile?  If `F.Promise` is mentioned in the error message but doesn't appear in the code, that's fishy.  In Play 2.5, `WSResponse.get` has the signature `java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage<WSResponse> get()` so `F.Promise` shouldn't be coming from there.  See [the javadoc](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/java/play/libs/ws/WSRequest.html#get--) for reference.
2. Check the versions of Play jars you have in your classpath.  If you're converting from 2.4 to 2.5, it's possible you still have dependencies which pull in Play 2.4 jars as transitive dependencies.  If you're not using an IDE, which should display the classpath for you, use a tool [like this one](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) to view dependencies.

**EDIT**

Based on the error message given in your comment, you're importing the wrong `WSResponse` class because you're mixing the Java and Scala APIs.  It looks like you're importing `play.api.libs.ws.WSResp‌​onse` instead of `play.libs.ws.WSResp‌​onse` (note the `api` part of the package, this denotes the Scala API).

Comment: Im saving the source before recompile. I added the output below after CompletionStage: `$ cat ./app/controllers/JavaController.java | grep "CompletionStage"
  public CompletionStage<Result> proxy() {
    final  CompletionStage<WSResponse> responsePromise = WS.url("http://example.com").get();` **I get the error:** `[error] /Play-2-JS-2.5/app/controllers/JavaController.java:87:  java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage<play.libs.ws.WSResponse> cannot be converted to java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage<play.api.libs.ws.WSResponse>
[error] WS.url("http://example.com").get().`

Comment: Answer updated - you're importing the wrong WSReponse class

Comment: Yaay! From your EDIT section, I was indeed using the wrong WSResponse. After switching the import statement to `import play.libs.ws.WSResp‌​onse; `, I no longer get the error! =D

Comment: Also, for anyone else who might come across this type of thing in the future (including myself), I just discovered https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/documentation/manual/releases/release25/migration25/JavaMigration25.md really helpful. 

The `Replaced F.Promise with Java 8's CompletionStage` section helped me figure out `.map` is replaced with `thenApplyAsync` by using the key, `map | thenApplyAsync`, where the pipe is what the call is replaced with where `||` is the next "batch" of replacements.